# useState and useRef initial values getting computed every re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

There's a thing I'm late to notice:

```js
const [object, setObject] = useState(new SomeObject());
```

Here, we construct an instance of `SomeObject` on **every single re-render**.
Then, if it's the component's initial render, it gets returned to `object`, otherwise it's just discarded.

Whatever is passed in as the initial argument is evaluated and discarded over and over again. It also better be pure, since re-renders can happen in arbitrary intervals and in arbitrary amounts. Given that constructing some objects or large arrays can be quite expensive, isn't it a bit suboptimal?

What's the solution here? Am I misunderstanding something, or such an elementary feature in React is implemented in such an suboptimal way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass a function to the `useState` hook to have your value [lazily initialized](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state).

For example:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(() => new SomeObject());
```

Comment: What if the initial state is in fact a function? Would you have to do `() => () => new SomeObject()`? Also this isn't possible with `useRef`, which I think it should because the same principle applies there.